# NameError while using Q object in a model method

Tags: django, django-models, django-q

```
class BlogList(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def get_first_article_image(self):
      if self.bloglist_articles.exists():
          bloglist = self.bloglist_articles.filter(
                          Q(image_link != '') | Q(image_file != '') ##<---error line
                                               ).order_by('-id')[:1].get()
          if bloglist.image_file:
              return '/'.join([settings.MEDIA_URL, bloglist.image_file.name])
          if bloglist.image_link:
              return bloglist.image_link
      return None

class BlogArticle(models.Model):
   bloglist = models.ForeignKey(BlogList, related_name='bloglist_articles')
   image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', default='', blank=True)
   image_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
   image_embed = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
```

if I call in template like

```
<a href="{{ bloglist_obj.get_first_article_image }}">{{bloglist.title}}</a>
```

I am getting

```
NameError at /
global name 'image_link' is not defined
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What view is giving you that error?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i am calling it in template, please see my update

Comment: What is the exact error line, because `bloglist.image_file` won't work - filter returns a list not an object.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid please see my update. now i posted my original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for Q objects is exactly the same as for filters: that is, you need to pass a keyword and a value, not an expression.

```
self.bloglist_articles.exclude(
    Q(image_link='') | Q(image_file='')
)
```

Comment: And exclude instead of filter. The point is that `image_link != ""` is an expression which presupposes the existence of a variable "image_link", whereas `image_link=""` is (in this case) a keyword argument with the value "".

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel gave you the answer, but really your entire method could be simplified to:

```
def get_first_article_image(self):
   q = self.bloglist_articles.exclude(image_link='', image_file='')
   if q.exists():
      return q[0]
   return None
```

In your template:

```
{% if bloglist_obj.get_first_article_image %}
   <a href="{{ bloglist_obj.get_first_article_image.image_link }}">
      <img src="{{ bloglist_obj.get_first_article_image.image_file.url }}">
   </a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: wow, so clean. thank you so much. i really need to learn to code cleanly